# Error on reify a version using ruby PaperTrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail

Added the paper_trail gem in the project Gemfile:

```
gem 'paper_trail'
```

Executed the following commands:

```
bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I have added the `has_paper_trail` to the model.

When I make a change on an instance of that model, I can see that a record is added to the versions table and I can access these records using `model.versions`.
I am trying now to reify one of the versions, but I am getting the following error:

```
/core/ruby/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/exceptions.rb:28: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
TypeError: uninitialized Time
from /core/ruby/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activemodel 6.1.4.7/lib/active_model/type/helpers/time_value.rb:29:in `nsec'
```

What I can see is that it fails in the following method when it's trying to evaluate `value.nsec`

```
def apply_seconds_precision(value)
  return value unless precision && value.respond_to?(:nsec)
  number_of_insignificant_digits = 9 - precision
  round_power = 10**number_of_insignificant_digits
  rounded_off_nsec = value.nsec % round_power

  if rounded_off_nsec > 0
    value.change(nsec: value.nsec - rounded_off_nsec)
  else
    value
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t. It is proprietary code. The model is also complex and I would need to share too much

Comment: Try using the [reproduction script](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug-report.md) to isolate the issue.

Comment: @JaredBeck I've added an update to my question. I know that is not so much, but I hope that if you cannot help me troubleshoot, you can help me implement a serailizer/deserializer for those type of objects.